# Why my overlay cannot cover bootstrap navigation bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add `overlay` in my project to protect user not to make a lot of interaction before content are fully downloaded. That's why I've added overlay as follow:

```
.overlay {
  opacity: 0.5; 
  background: #000; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  position: fixed; 
}
```

But problem is that overlay can cover 100% of all entire page except bootstrap navigation bar. Please help me how to cover that overlay on bootstrap navigation bar.

```
<div class="overlayIndex"></div>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">.......</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-view="" autoscroll="true"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Set your `z-index` to 1031 and see if that does the trick?

Comment: set `z-index` more then `navbar` like that: `z-index:9999`

Comment: @cwanjt can you post as answer?

Comment: posting right  now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `z-index` to 1031. Bootstrap's `navbar-fixed-top` uses a z-index of 1030. Setting it above this should allow your overlay to cover the entire viewport.

Bootstrap's CSS for `navbar-fixed-top` class:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5; 
  background: #000; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  position: fixed; 
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400?text=IMAGE" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Sell $</h3>
          <p>Money Money.</p>
        </div>      
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400?text=Another Image Maybe" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>More Sell $</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```